# Inconsistent styling of the name Winter Bash

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

The description for [Spotless](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/spotless) states:

> [image]
>
> No edits or flags on a positive, open question asked during **Winterbash** for one week.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*

“Winterbash” strikes me as a little odd since it [has always been two words](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/15/millinery-on-the-stack-join-us-for-winter-summer-bash-2021/).

Could this be updated?

Comment: Going for the unicorn badge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one slipped us by!

Thanks for pointing it out, it has been updated, appreciate the help!