# Hat description to be updated as "Winter Bash" instead of "WinterBash"

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2022

As per [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303384/312043), the Winter Bash event is called "Winter Bash", with a space.

In plain text:

> The official name of the event has always been Winter Bash, with a space, and that's how it's been typed in all of our blog announcements.

In [this year](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/)'s hats section, the description for the "Squared Away" and "Cubed Away" hats are below:

> Post 4 answers on 4 separate sites during **WinterBash**

> Post 4 questions and 4 answers on 4 separate sites during Post 4 questions and 4 answers on 4 separate sites during **WinterBash**

For consistency, can we have the description as "Winter Bash" instead of "WinterBash"?

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Winter Bash]

Comment: Winter Summer Bash?

Comment: [Occurred last year too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374163/inconsistent-styling-of-the-name-winter-bash).

Comment: The [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303384/1052107) you attached with the question clearly states "that's not necessarily how it's always typed in casual conversation or on Meta, and Winterbash is also a fairly common substitution".

Comment: @JitendraSingh Yeah... but our actual UI isn't casual conversation or on Meta. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *tried* to make everything consistent beforehand, I swear! Guess this was one missed. Fixed!